# Laravel Frozennode/Administrator get current admin users id and pass it as a default value

Tags: php, laravel

What I am trying to do is pass the currently logged in admin user_id of Frozennode/Administrator as a value of the editable fields array. That way I can keep track of who has edited what, I am sure this is probably very simple but no matter what I try I just can't seem to get it.

```
<?php
 $admin_user_id = Auth::user()->getId();
 return array(
     // usual frozennode stuff.. 
     'edit_fields' => array(
         'heading' => array(
             'title' => 'Heading',
             'type' => 'text'
         ),
         'images' => array(
             'title' => 'Image',
             'type' => 'image',
             'location' => public_path() . '/img/content/',
             'naming' => 'random',
             'length' => 20
         ),
         'user_id' => array(
             'title' => 'Admin User',
             'type' => 'text',
             'editable' => false,
             'value' => $admin_user_id
         ),
     ),
);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hiya, it gives me:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getId() but the method exists on the User model

Comment: Is it a public method? If not make it public.

Comment: yes it is a public method